Issue in Kafka broker election in windows using Kraft

I'm running 2 kafka server using Kraft on windows. There is only single topic with replication factor 2 on the. If my one server stops or fails i want server2 to serve as leader but it fails to do so.
I want server 2 to take over as leader and there should be no data loss.
My server.properties are
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9093,2@localhost:9095
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=C:/kafka/K-LOG
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2

log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000


My server 1 properties are
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=2
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9093,2@localhost:9095
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094,CONTROLLER://:9095
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9094
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=C:/kafka/K-LOG
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=2
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2

log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.
